# Converting INT to Datetime object in Pandas

Tags: datetime, format, integer

I have a date column like below on a dataframe .(Its datatype is integer)
Year    Price
2009    4
2010    6
20111   9

When I want to convert the Year column into Datetime object it turns it into something like 2009-01-01.
And then I want to show only the year part which is 2009 by doing

new_df['Year'] = new_df['Year'].dt.year

It shows the year but this time in converts the 'Year' column back into integer.
Is there no way of displaying 'Only the year part'without the column getting converted back to Integer?
Thanks

Comment: The  'date'  column is like   2009, 2010,2011,2012 ...

Comment: if this is just about how things are *displayed*, why not use `strftime`, e.g. `new_df['Year'].dt.strftime('%Y')`

Comment: This  it converts it back into 'Object' again.I guess you cannot just display the 'year' part of a 'datetime' object

Comment: Yeah, just don't care so much how things are displayed, as long as the calculations are right ;-) For e.g. a presentation, you can still export to Excel easily and do some "optical tweaking" there.